# How to split value from Emun (tuple) and insert it next to each other (the halves)

Tags: elixir

Ok so I got an Enum with tuples inside like this:

```
    [
          {"-", "-", "-", "7", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "0", "-"},
          {"-", "-", "5", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
          {"-", "5", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "7", "-", "-"},
          {"5", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "5", "-", "-", "-"}
    ]
```

And I want it like this

```
    [
          {"-", "-", "-", "7", "-", "-"},
          {"-", "-", "5", "-", "-", "-"},
          {"-", "5", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
          {"5", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
          {"-", "-", "-", "-", "0", "-"},
          {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
          {"-", "-", "-", "7", "-", "-"},
          {"-", "-", "5", "-", "-", "-"}           
    ]
```

Note that the "horizontal" half became values after the ones already in there
I tried using Enum.zip but I'm very new at this (I first passed the Tuples to lists)
I'd really like some help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flat map your tuples to their halfs. The conversion to list and back would be required in the generic case:

```rb
Enum.flat_map(input, fn t ->
  list = Tuple.to_list(t)
  list
  |> Enum.chunk_every(div(length(list), 2))
  |> Enum.map(&List.to_tuple/1)
end)
#⇒ [
#    {"-", "-", "-", "7", "-", "-"},
#    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "0", "-"},
#    {"-", "-", "5", "-", "-", "-"},
#    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
#    {"-", "5", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
#    {"-", "-", "-", "7", "-", "-"},
#    {"5", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
#    {"-", "-", "5", "-", "-", "-"}
# ]
```

---

To achieve the exact result you posted as expected, you should collect the outcome into two arrays and join them afterward, or to partition the result.

```rb
with {bottom, top} <-
     Enum.reduce(input, {[], []}, fn t, {top, bottom} ->
       l = Tuple.to_list(t)
       [t, b] =
         l
         |> Enum.chunk_every(div(length(l), 2))
         |> Enum.map(&List.to_tuple/1)
       {[t|top], [b|bottom]}
     end) do
  [top, bottom]
  |> Enum.map(&Enum.reverse/1)
  |> Enum.reduce(&Kernel.++/2)
end
```

---

*Bonus track:* using a single pipeline.

```rb
input
|> Enum.reduce({[], []}, fn t, {top, bottom} ->
  l = Tuple.to_list(t)
  [t, b] =
    l
    |> Enum.chunk_every(div(length(l), 2))
    |> Enum.map(&List.to_tuple/1)
  {[t|top], [b|bottom]}
end)
|> Tuple.to_list()
|> Enum.reduce(&Kernel.++/2)
|> Enum.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose your list is named `list`.

You can reduce the whole thing in one pass:

```
Enum.reduce(list, [[], []], fn(t, [l1, l2]) ->
  [la, lb] =
    t
    |> Tuple.to_list()
    |> Enum.chunk_every(div(tuple_size(t), 2))

  [
    [l1, List.to_tuple(la)],
    [l2, List.to_tuple(lb)]
  ]
end) |> List.flatten()
```

Here, the reduce is starting with an accumulator that contains two empty lists.

The line `[la, lb] = Tuple.to_list(t) |> Enum.chunk_every(div(tuple_size(t), 2))` splits your tuple into two lists and assigns them to `la` and `lb`.

Then, You produce the list with two lists to pass on as the accumulator to the next iteration.

`[l1, List.to_tuple(la)]` adds `la` to the end of the first list, following whatever is on the first list of the accumulator.

The same is done to the second half of the list.

> Notice that this will only work for tuples with even length, since Enum.chunk_by/2 is chunking by half the length of your tuples, if your tuple has an odd length, it will generate three chunks, with the third having only one element. Thus it won't match the `[la, lb]` assignment, causing an error.

At the end you're left with two lists containing the left and right halves of your tuples, so you just need to flatten them with `List.flatten/1`

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution is simpler but I had to use Aleksei's for the nature of my code. If i had to just do what I said in the post i'd have gone for your solution.